# In HTML5, how do I align multiple elements to appear on the same line in a list definition?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML definition.
(I'm using Knockout)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: itemList">
   <li>
       <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>
       <span class="right" data-bind="text: measurement"></span>
       <input type="checkbox" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

**I would like these to display aligned as the following**

```
Item1                   measurement1  Checkbox1
Item2                   measurement2  Checkbox2
Item3                   measurement3  Checkbox3
```

I would like this to be aligned the following way:

> Column 1 is floated to the far left.
>
> Column 3 (The input checkbox) is floated to the far right.
>
> Column 2 is is on the far right, but to the left of Column3

I've tried working with DIVs and the float/display attributes.

I haven't been able to achieve the desired visual behavior.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float and text-align ?

```css
li {
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
  width:200px;/* whatever width you set here or in parent */
  }
li :first-child {
  float:left;
  }
input {
  vertical-align:middle;/* ? */
  }
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: itemList">
   <li>
       <span data-bind="text: displayName">item</span>
       <span class="right" data-bind="text: measurement">measure</span>
       <input type="checkbox" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use Bootstrap's grid system — you would be able to specify the proportional width of each column. Additionally, it becomes easier to handle its responsiveness to screensize.

In your case, you might use it like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: itemList">
     <li>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
           <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
           <span class="right" data-bind="text: measurement"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
           <input type="checkbox" />
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

See more grid examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

--

If you are trying to present tabular data, you might also consider using HTML tables and specifying its percentage column width.

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend a [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? I put a growing spacer in to push the middle column over to the right. Modifying GCyrillus' answer:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  width: 90%;
  /* whatever width you set here or in parent */
}

li .spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  }
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: itemList">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: displayName">item</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <span class="right" data-bind="text: measurement">measure</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </li>
</ul>
```